# Custom design of Google Adsense

Tags: adsense, google-ads-api

I have seen some websites having custom design of the adsense, How is this possible. 
Does anyone have the idea how to create a custom made design of the google adsense.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because they are AdSense Premium Publishers. You can only become a member if you are invited. And you need about 1 million page views a month before that will happen!